# Use @Html.EditorForModel() without polluting my domain entities with mvc assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, editorformodel

Is it possible to use the `@Html.EditorForModel()` method but not pollute my Domain entities like Product with `HiddenInput`,`DataType(MultiLine)` etc.. Attributes which needs the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but it will use the default for rendering things.
For example: strings will be one line textboxes.

There is no way to put this metadata somewhere else. (Unless you write new HTML helper by your own.)

What we usually do is, use a `ViewModel` for each Domain entity, and there we put the metadata.

Comment: sorry, but I don`t get your answer. I guess I should use viewmodels for this stuff right? Viewmodels for input validation ?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov. I guess that if I had mention never use `ViewBag` I would get another upvote from you... **:)** thanks master!

Comment: That's worth mentioning only when you see that the OP is making the mistake of using it :-) But, yes, basically every post that recommends the usage of view models and recommends against ViewData/ViewBag gets my upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have two models - one is the domain entity, the other is specifically contains the attributes I want. Then I map/copy between the two of them. I have a simple class that automatically copies properties from one object to another, but you can manually do this or use something like [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). Then you use @Html.EditorFor against this new model.